# Async execution with WxWidgets

Tags: c++, asynchronous, wxwidgets

I am developing an engineering program with **WxWidgets** and **Codeblocks** on Windows that dependent some Bash scripts.
I want to run the program with a **seperate Bash window not Windows Command Prompt** (to print out colored outputs to Bash console).

Is there any EASY way to run commands asynchronously with WxWidgets, because the samples that came with Wx-2.8 is contains 1231 lines of code and i dont have much more time.

```
wxShell(_("bash --login -i"));  // This locks the program until bash window closed
wxShell(_("bash -c grep bla bla")); //This works great but on CMD but


// I want to run on bash.exe like that
wxShell(_("egrep bla bla"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the function [wxExecute](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_processfunctions.html#wxexecute) with with flag `wxEXEC_ASYC`. Something like:

```
wxExecute(_("bash --login -i"), wxEXEC_ASYNC);
```

should do what you need. If you want to redirect input and output then you will also need [wxProcess](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxprocess.html#wxprocess).